# Partial class в WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

Здравствуйте. При использовании WCF появилась такая проблема - не обновляются некоторые данные на клиенте пока не перезапущу сервер. Мне подсказали что эта проблема решается разделением логики моих сущностей с помощью partial. Сущности лежат в отдельной DAL, соответственно где мне надо создавать partial классы этих сущностей, если на клиенте, то правильно ли то, что они должны иметь один и тот namespace?

Comment: Может так не надо делать, и кто подскажет почему данные в сущностях не обновляются(использую singleton для работы с бд)

Comment: А на сервере-то это данные обновляются? Может у вас сервер кэш не обновляет вовремя? Под отладкой посмотрите

Comment: partial-классы - это способ разнести код одного класса на несколько файлов, только и всего. Или вы что-то другое так называете?

Comment: @rdorn Потестировал, узнал, что не обновляются данные, например, TotalCount(это свойство только с геттером и с пустым сеттером). В нем логика -> берем поле из навигационного свойства и делаем расчеты

Comment: И вот такое свойство тоже не обновляется. Хотя когда без WCF делал, все было отлично [DataMember]
        public List<FittingProduct> FittingProduct
        {
            get
            {
                return DM.FittingProduct.GetList().Where(x => x.ProductId == this.Id).ToList();
            }
            set { }
        }

Comment: Тут без отладчика мало что сказать можно. По каждому случаю нужно смотреть откуда данные должны браться, что берется в текущий момент, разбираться почему именно так. То есть не просто посмотреть что значение правильное или не правильное, но и пройти все этапы его получения, чтобы понять. в каком месте оно стало неправильным и почему. Это и есть собственно отладка. Помнится, при разработке одного парсера приходилось опускаться до ручного анализа входных XML, чтобы найти, на чем именно он падает и выбрать подходящий вариант обхода проблемы.

Comment: @rdron Правильно ли утверждение, что навигационные свойства не содержат атрибут [DataMember]?

Comment: Без понятия, в коде смотреть надо.

Comment: @rdorn я просто хочу расширить классы, чтобы в библиотеке они содержали чисто поля из бд, а в другом месте расширить их нав. свойствами и свойствами бизнес-логики

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72841/discussion-between-rdorn-and-ari100krat).